# Script using the createCourses function using data from a sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom, google-workspace

I am creating a script using the createCourses function. The template code provided on google development support is where this began. Now I want to manipulate the template to pull data from a spreadsheet. Debuggin is giving me an error - "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "name" at 'course': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list." The data appears to be pulled but I can't figure out how to repeat the create function for all my courses.

Here is my code... I have replaced the sheets 'ID' on purpose!

```
function createCourses() {

  var course;
  course = Classroom.newCourse();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');

  course.name = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  course.ownerId = ss.getRange("H2:H").getValues();
  //course.id = "Bio10";

  course = Classroom.Courses.create(course);
  Logger.log('%s (%s)', course.name, course.id);

  var list = Classroom.Courses.create();
  Logger.log(create);

}
```

Comment: What does your logs say?

Comment: Logs don't return any data... Execution Transcript...                              
[17-07-07 09:17:10:199 EDT] Range.getValues() [0 seconds]
[17-07-07 09:17:10:237 EDT] Execution failed: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "name" at 'course': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "owner_id" at 'course': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list. (line 12, file "Code") [0.26 seconds total runtime]

Answer (score 0):

You don't say but I assume you are getting the error on the line `var list = Classroom.Courses.create();` you're not passing any parameters to the `.create()` method.

To repeat the function you would just need to pull the range of data from the spreadsheet and use a for loop to iterate through the data and create your courses.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The error actually appears at 'course = Classroom.Courses.create(course); ' If this makes a difference in your response?